Finding a function with certain conditions
I'm trying to find a function $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{>0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following properties:

$f$ must be continuous (the smoother the better) in both variables.
$f$ must be INCREASING in the first variable $x$, and DECREASING in the second variable $y$
$f$ must be scale invariant, that is $f(cx,cy) = f(x,y)$ for any $c>0$

This is intended to replace the initial candidate $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$, because it is increasing in $y$ when $x < 0$. I'm trying to find many such functions to see which one fits my needs better, but I'm not even sure such a function exists, and ideally we can extend the second variable's domain to be all of $\mathbb{R}$ if possible.
Thanks.

When $x = 0$ your scale invariance says $f(0, cy) = f(0,y)$ for $c > 0$.  That says $f$ is constant on the ray $x=0, y>0$, but it conflicts with your requirement that $f$ is decreasing in $y$.

@RobertIsrael It doesn't have to be strictly decreasing (or increasing for $x$)

How about a constant function then? Satisfies all your requirements.

Sure, but I'm looking for a more interesting example.

@Abezhiko that is not scale invariant.

According to your scale invariance, for $y > 0$ we have
$ f(x,y) = f(x/y, 1)$, let's call that $g(x/y)$.
Now $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{g'(x/y)}{y} \ \text{and}\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =  - \frac{g'(x/y) x}{y^2} $$
Now if $x < 0$ and $y > 0$, $1/y$ and $-x/y^2$ are both positive, so these have the same sign.  Thus it is impossible to have your $f$ increasing in $x$ and decreasing in $y$ in this region unless $f$ is actually constant there.
